# diff between two files ignore empty lines

Tags: diff

I want to make diff between two files ignoring the empty lines, but preserve the original line number in the files.
File1:

```
hhhh



gggg
ffff
```

File2:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Diff:

```
1,6c1,3
< hhhh
<
<
<
< gggg
< ffff
---
> aaa
> bbb
> ccc
```

I want: (preserve 1,6c1,3)

```
1,6c1,3
< hhhh
< gggg
< ffff
---
> aaa
> bbb
> ccc
```

I've tried diff -B, diff -I "\n" but it doesn't work. 
Does anyone know how I can do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with perl:
diff file1 file2 | perl -ne ' print if (!/<\s*$/)'